# Clip Shapefiles via Iteration in QGIS Python Script

Tags: python, iteration, qgis, qpython

I have two polygon shapefiles with several objects. Each object in both shapefiles has a given ID number. Now I want to clip the object with ID=1 in Shapefile A with the object with ID=1 in Shapefile B.

However each shapefile has about 5000 objects, so I would like to create a Python script via the QGIS graphical modeler. I know how to use the graphical modeler to clip objects and stuff, but I cannot find any iteration option within the modeler. Is there an option to do so or how can I implement an iteration directly into the script to get the wanted clip results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [qpython] tag probably irrelevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is a better fit for https://gis.stackexchange.com. Most of the [qgis] questions here are related to the development of QGIS itself.

Comment: Done. Thank you.